# Error Function That Store Errors In a Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, error-handling, pdo

i have this function that i use to handle my errors
within php query and things like that

but i thought it will be better that if i can save the errors in the database then show it up in my admin control panel, so no one can see the errors that i have on my website

here is the function :

```
function er($str) {
global $db;
if (!$str) {
$errornum = $db->errorinfo();
echo $errornum[2];
die;
  }
}
```

and here i was trying to do what i said i want to do :

```
function er($str) {
global $db;
if (!$str) {
$errornum = $db->errorinfo();
$en = $errornum[2];
echo "".$en."";
$db->query("INSERT INTO `error` (`con`) VALUES ('$en')");
die;
  }
}
```

---

```
The Problem Is :
```

> that the query dosent do anything

```
The Reason Is :
```

> i believe that the reason is that $en is empty ... so the insert wont do anything as it dosent have a name to insert it into the database , but $en isnt empty as when i echo it i dose output the error .. i fugure that out while i was trying to get it work i replaced $en with (Example) and it worked and (Example) was there in the database

```
Fix :
```

> I'm not sure but i think if i can get it to paste the real value of the $en .. then it will be working :D
>
> But i need you to help me to do it or point me to the right direction

Comment: Storing database errors in a database is quite err... recursive.

Comment: Did you consider a log file by chance?

Comment: @Dev this is not a good idea at all, look at your log files as mentioned above

Comment: If you don't want users to see your errors turn your error reporting off in your live environment

Comment: @allen213 its not about that its about making the possibility to see the error from the cpanel and when ever an error popup i will see it in the cpanel ( so i dont need to look around pages to see if there is an error or wait for users to report me )

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes i was considering by doing it with a log file but i dont have one single idea how to do it so i though  it will be better to do it this way as i know how to use it this way

Comment: @YourCommonSense if you could post me an article or something to how doing it by using log file i'll be thankful

Comment: @YourCommonSense's remark about recursiveness means this: often when your php app is getting errors it's because of some trouble with the database. If you log error messages to the data base the logging may fail, and generate errors, because the data base in unavailable.

Comment: @OllieJones probable wont be a big problem to me because I'm only want to use it for query and small errors like that but when the database unavailable it will show the error on screen and `die;` so it wont cause more errors to show up and that is easy to notice but when it come to an query error in a page you wouldn't know about it until someone tells you or you go around for error searching :D

Comment: I wonder who upvoting this latter comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.

What you have to get rid of:

- no die()
- no errors echoed to browser
- no database logging

What you really have to do:

- set proper error reporting for PHP. On a live server it have to be

  ```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors',0);
  ini_set('log_errors',1);
  ```
- make your PDO throw exceptions as explained here: [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15990858/285587)

this way you will see all your errors in cpanel and none of them will be spat to the user.

Comment: this will do what i want, but as i said its a CMS script so i will puplish it soon ... and its not going to be good Script when every one install the script on his site will need to do that .. i thought maybe logging the errors in file within the script files, then include it in the script cpanel

Comment: you can use [error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) directive as well

Comment: thank you .. that what i wanted , `error_log("Error Example \n", 3, "logs.php");`

Comment: You don't need this command. You don't need to handle errors manually AT ALL. PHP can do it all for you. And do it way better.

Answer (score -1):

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO `error` (`con`) VALUES ('$en')");
```

instead try

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO `error` (`con`) VALUES ('".$en."') )";
```

If its echoing the error I doubt that $en is empty so its probably just a string interpolation issue.

Comment: i have tried this before , didnt work .. but thank you for trying

Comment: what is the issue you are talking about? what's wrong with string interpolation?

Comment: @YourCommonSense well i guess he means that sometimes a `''` dosent work so you have to use `'".."'` but in my case i've tried both